# Filling Gaps in Time Series Data in R

Tags: r, time-series

So this question has been bugging me for a while since I've been looking for an efficient way of doing it. Basically, I have a dataframe, with a data sample from an experiment in each row. I guess this should be looked at more as a log file from an experiment than the final version of the data for analyses.

The problem that I have is that, from time to time, certain events get logged in a column of the data. To make the analyses tractable, what I'd like to do is "fill in the gaps" for the empty cells between events so that each row in the data can be tied to the most recent event that has occurred. This is a bit difficult to explain but here's an example:

[image: Screenshot of dataframe from RStudio of base dataset]

Now, I'd like to take that and turn it into this:

[image]

Doing so will enable me to split the data up by the current event. In any other language I would jump into using a for loop to do this, but I know that R isn't great with loops of that type, and, in this case, I have hundreds of thousands of rows of data to sort through, so am wondering if anyone can offer suggestions for a speedy way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: See `?na.locf' (last occurrence carried forward) in the zoo package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `na.locf()` function in package **zoo** is useful here, e.g.

```
require(zoo)
dat <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, sample_value = c(34,56,78,98,234),
                  log_message = c("FIRST_EVENT", NA, "SECOND_EVENT", NA, NA))

dat <-
  transform(dat,
            Current_Event = sapply(strsplit(as.character(na.locf(log_message)), 
                                            "_"),
                                   `[`, 1))
```

Gives

```
> dat
  ID sample_value  log_message Current_Event
1  1           34  FIRST_EVENT         FIRST
2  2           56         <NA>         FIRST
3  3           78 SECOND_EVENT        SECOND
4  4           98         <NA>        SECOND
5  5          234         <NA>        SECOND
```

To explain the code,

1. `na.locf(log_message)` returns a factor (that was how the data were created in `dat`) with the `NA`s replaced by the previous non-`NA` value (the last one carried forward part).
2. The result of 1. is then converted to a character string
3. `strplit()` is run on this character vector, breaking it apart on the underscore. `strsplit()` returns a list with as many elements as there were elements in the character vector. In this case each component is a vector of length two. We want the first elements of these vectors,
4. So I use `sapply()` to run the subsetting function `'['()` and extract the 1st element from each list component.
5. The whole thing is wrapped in `transform()` so i) I don;t need to refer to `dat$` and so I can add the result as a new variable directly into the data `dat`.

Comment: Excellent - elegant and exactly what I'm after!

Comment: @plone Thanks. I added some explanation of the code as it was a bit more than just `na.locf()` to get *exactly* the output you showed.

Comment: The explanation is really helpful too, great for people like me :)

Answer (score 5):

This question has been asked in various forms on this site many times. The standard answer is to use `zoo::na.locf`. Search [r] for `na.locf` to find examples how to use it.

Here is an alternative way in base R using `rle`:

```
d <- data.frame(LOG_MESSAGE=c('FIRST_EVENT', '', 'SECOND_EVENT', '', ''))
within(d, {
    # ensure character data
    LOG_MESSAGE <- as.character(LOG_MESSAGE)
    CURRENT_EVENT <- with(rle(LOG_MESSAGE), # list with 'values' and 'lengths'
                          rep(replace(values, 
                                      nchar(values)==0, 
                                      values[nchar(values) != 0]), 
                              lengths))
})
#    LOG_MESSAGE CURRENT_EVENT
# 1  FIRST_EVENT   FIRST_EVENT
# 2                FIRST_EVENT
# 3 SECOND_EVENT  SECOND_EVENT
# 4               SECOND_EVENT
# 5               SECOND_EVENT
```

Comment: Perfect - many thanks to you - I had failed to see the use of this function before now, but it's turning out to be very fast indeed, which is great!